# How can I use a static method with another returntype like the class where the method is coded

Tags: java, logging, static

I'm trying to code a new Logger class which use the `org.slf4j.Logger` and its own `LogUtil` class.

So here is my problem. I want to try to create a static method called  `getInstance()` which will be initialized with the variable of the class `Vlogger`. But the return type of the method is `Logger`.

```
public class VLogger  {
    private static LogMessageBuilder logMessageBuilder;
    private LogUtil logUtil;

    public static Logger getInstance() {
        // String className = new Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(Reflection.getCallerClass().toString());
    }}
```

Here can you see the old call and the new one that I want:

```
Vlogger vlog = VLogger.getInstance();
```

Vs.:

```
private static Logger LOG =
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResourceStatements.class);
```

Comment: Don't. Do. This. Please. Just use Slf4j as it was intended - this sort of "logging utility `class`" only ever makes things worse.

Comment: P.S. you know what a spell checker is ... right?

Comment: P.P.S if you are considering unrolling the stack to working out the caller - don't do that either. In short - abandon this idea; it's awful.

Comment: @BoristheSpider lol. +3 virtual comment upvotes, distributed amongst them however you see fit

Comment: so this i not my idea hahah. I'm in a aprenticeship and my teamleader sayd taht I should do that. Idk why, but I dont make sense to me hahah

Comment: So what's the problem? Just wrap the logger in your class and return it.

Comment: show me how,idk?

Comment: @shmosel   i dont know haha

Comment: What is so darned funny?

Comment: @shmosel if one does that then every single log message comes from `line 3 org.stupid.VLogger`. Every time I see that I want to find the person whose idea it was and make _them_ debug the problem in production.

Comment: @LewBloch now _that_ I would also like to know.

Comment: @LewBloch, nothing is funny, I just dont know how to slove this problem. the Idea of my teamleader make sense for me, but way how I should do it dont make sense. btw have a nice weekend

Comment: It was all that laughing had me asking.

Comment: @LewBloch sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the anwser:

```
public static VLogger getInstance() {
        VLogger result = new VLogger();
        result.l = LoggerFactory.getLogger(new Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName());
        return result;
    }
```

and the call:

```
vLogger.message("Folgende Statements wurden verwednet").att(test, m).debug();
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider